# How can I load a custom PDF when user(s) trying to print my page out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

**Goal**

The `media="print"`on my page is horrible and I want to improve it.
Basically, I want to improve the look of my page when my users print it out.

**I'm thinking . . .**

Rather than, hiding and showing a lot of items on my page on `media="print"`.
I decided to hide my page completely, and load a PDF instead. The PDF that I made. I'm not sure if this is the best approach for this, but I find that save a lot of time, and still have a full control in term of showing/hiding objects.

---

**HTML**

```
<body >

  <span id="web">
    <!-- My whole site structure -->
  </span>

  <span id="print"><iframe src="img/USER.pdf" width="100%" height="830" ></span>


</body>
```

Within my `<body>`, I have a PDF

`<span id="print"><iframe src="img/name.pdf" width="100%" height="830" ></span>`

I hide that PDF thoughout my whole page by doing :

```
#print{
    display: none;
  }
```

Then, when the user want to print my page out. I want to load this PDF back, and hide my whole site.

**CSS**

```
/*Hide the whole page*/
#web{
    display: none;
}


/*Show PDF back*/
#print{
    display:block!important;
}
```

---

**Result**

It works, but unfortunately, it's only work in Safari. 
Not Chrome, Not Firefox.

- What is the most efficient way to achieve something like this ?
- Can someone help me fix this to work with all browsers ?
- Is there any **JS**, or **jQuery** plug-in that will help me accomplish this ?

If there is anything else that I can provide, let me know.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have a link to download the pdf if they wanted to?

Comment: I can do that, but I just want to my media="print" to look at its best also. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Will your PDF have only one page always? It does not look like a good approach, if your users have no active PDF plugin it'll also fail..

Comment: PDFs have specific printing instructions embedded into them.  You should just link to your PDF so that it works properly.  An image of a PDF is not the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you that like my approach and looking for a solution for this, Here is how I come up with. I convert my PDF to an image (.PNG).

---

## Adjust your HTML structure

Wrap them around a `div` or `span`.

```
<span id="web">
<!-- Whole HTML structure -->
</span>


<span id="print" style="display: none;" >
    <img src="img/Image.png" width="90%">
</span>
```

---

## Link to a print stylesheet.

Add this to the top of your page.

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="css/print.css"  />`

---

## Recap

I hide my image as a start.

```
`<span id="print" style="display: none;" ><img src="img/Image.png" width="90%"></span>`
```

Then, I show it back when the user is in the print mode, another word `media =print`, then my print.css will kick in.

**print.css**

```
/*Hide the whole page*/
#web{
    display: none;
}


/*Show Image back*/
#print{
    display:block!important;
    background-color: white;

}
```

## Result

When the user trying to print, now they should see something like this :

[image]

This should work on any browsers, since it just an image.

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern for this would be to supply a link with text such as "Printable Version". You would then simply link to the PDF in a non-suprising way for the user.

If you want to persist with the CSS print layout, I have had some success with the [CSS paged media specification](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201312/Blog/Printing-Web-Pages-With-The-Paged-Media-Module/).

Here is a sample CSS file - note that only a tiny amount is in a `print` style...

```
body {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

h2 {
    string-set: title content();
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.on-new-page {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
}

.keep-together {
    page-break-before: avoid;
}

.keep-intact {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.contents a::after {
  content: leader('.') target-counter(attr(href), page);
}

@page {
    margin: 2.54cm;
    size: portrait;
}

@page :left {
    margin-right: 3.18cm;

    @bottom-left {
        content: counter(page);
    }

    @top-left {
        content: string(title);
    }
}

@page :right {
    margin-left: 3.18cm;

    @bottom-right {
        content: counter(page);
    }

    @top-right {
        content: string(title);
    }
}

@page :first {
    margin-top: 10cm;
}

@media print {
    .dont-print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

You can check out my [example page](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/pagedmedia.html) and do a print preview to see the effects this has. It varies by browser, but you can see there is much more control now than there used to be over print layouts.

Comment: I'm not planning to style the whole page at `media = print` I'm trying to load something that are good enough to print, so I don't have to do a lot of work in media print.